# How to output the largest number in keySet if there are several such numbers?

Tags: java

How to output the largest word if there are several such numbers? (should output the one, which occurs earlier). My code didn't work properly.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class solved {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] str = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (int i=1; i < str.length; i++) {
             int n = str[i].length();
             String s = str[i];
             hashMap.put(n, s);
         }
         int maxKey = Collections.max(hashMap.keySet());
         System.out.println(hashMap.get(maxKey));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)) to avoid ovewriting an existing value and keep the earliest values

```
for (int i=1; i < str.length; i++) {
    int n = str[i].length();
    String s = str[i];
    hashMap.putIfAbsent(n, s); 
}
```

⚠️ Starting `i` at `1` makes the first word unused be careful, array are `0-indexed` so start at `0` to get on every word

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a `HashMap`, if you have an entry later with a duplicate key, the previous entry will be overwritten. One way to deal with this would be to have a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` but that's just too complicated. It's better to just do it like this:

```
int longestN = -1;
String longest;
for (String s : str) {
  int n = s.length();
  if (n > longestN) {
    longestN = n;
    longest = s;
  }
}
System.out.println(longest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to store all words? In your exaple "dog" will replace "cat", so you lose the first word. If you want to store *all* words, you cannot have an `Integer` as key in a `HashMap`, because it can only ever have a single key for each value.

If you want to retain all words for some later use, you can invert your map to `Map<String, Integer>` - and use words as keys and lengths as values. Or, you could skip using Collections altogether:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] str = scan.nextLine().split(" ");

    int longestWordLength = -1;
    for (String s : str) {
        if (s.length() > longestWordLength)
            longestWordLength = s.length();
    }

    for (String s : str) {
        if (s.length() == longestWordLength)
            System.out.printf("Longest word: %s is %s", s, s.length());
    }
}
```

Or, with Java 8 streams for fun and learning:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] str = scan.nextLine().split(" ");

    int longest = Arrays.stream(str)
            .mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(-1);
    Predicate<String> isLongest = s -> s.length() == longest;
    String firstLongest = Arrays.stream(str)
            .filter(isLongest).findFirst().orElse("no words");

    System.err.println(firstLongest + " " + longest);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Collectors.maxBy()` be a little more efficient since you don't go through the list twice (although I guess performance doesn't really matter here)?

Comment: Not going for efficiency here, as you noted. Even with loops I'm doing that twice, so your example is definitely better - just wanted to keep the ideas of finding max and the picking first word that matches separate.